# Ability of Outlook Add-ins on iPhone to Write and Read Email Content

Tags: ios, email, outlook, office-addins

I am developing an Outlook Add-in where I wish to append a verification code to the body of an email when it's being sent to a user, and later on, read that email to verify the code when the email is received. This is somewhat similar to a 2-step verification process. I have implemented this logic successfully on Outlook for desktop using Office.js.

However, I am facing challenges when trying to implement the same for Outlook on iPhone. Specifically, I'm not sure if Outlook Add-ins on iPhone have the capability to write to and read from email content.

Here's a simplified version of what I am aiming to achieve:

When an email is being sent, append a verification code to the email body.
When that email is received, read the email body to verify the code.
I have the following permissions set in my manifest file:

xml code

```
<Permissions>ReadWriteItem</Permissions>
```

And I have set up my add-in to run on the ItemSend and ItemRead events.

My questions are:

- Do Outlook Add-ins on iPhone support writing to and reading from the
  email body?
- If yes, is there any specific setup or permissions required to
  achieve this on iPhone?
- Are there any known limitations or differences in handling this on
  iPhone compared to desktop?

I would greatly appreciate any insights or references to documentation that can guide me on how to implement this functionality on iPhone.

Thank you!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/outlook-mobile-addins